# How to handle deprecation of 'project' parameter for combineLatest (in rxjs from 6.5)

Tags: rxjs

In RXJS 6.5 the signature for combineLatest in the following code is deprecated:

```
import { combineLatest, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

const a$ = interval().pipe(
  take(3),
  map( x => `a: ${x}`)
);
const b$ = interval().pipe(
  take(3),
  map( x => x + 10 ),
  map( x => `b: ${x}`)
);
combineLatest(a$, b$, (a, b) => `${a} / ${b}`)
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

The output is:

```
a: 0 / b: 10
a: 1 / b: 10
a: 1 / b: 11
a: 2 / b: 11
a: 2 / b: 12
```

The problem here is the scheduler. The deprecation message does not really help me:

> // With a scheduler (deprecated) /** @deprecated Passing a scheduler
>   here is deprecated, use {@link subscribeOn} and/or {@link observeOn}
>   instead */

How can I make this code compatible with RXJS 6.5?

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-result-selector-migration

Comment: @cartant Thank you, I havn't seen this documentaion part. That is helpful, I don't know if the deprecation message is helpful here.

Comment: Yeah, I know: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4776

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @cartant I can answer my own question now:

```
combineLatest([a$, b$])
  .pipe(map( x => ((a, b) => `${a} / ${b}`)(...x)))
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error when passing a variable. You can ignore the pipe.

```js
{
    const values: Observable<any[]>[] = Object.values(subscriptions$);
    return combineLatest<string[][]>(values).pipe(
      map((variableValues) => {
        let newInput = input;
        variableValues.forEach((variableValue, i) => {
          const key = keys[i];
          const value = variableValue.find(v => v !== undefined);
          const regex = new RegExp(`${this.escapeRegExp(key)}`, 'g');
          newInput = newInput.replace(regex, value);
        });
        return newInput;
      })
    );
}
```

Deprecation message:

```
(alias) combineLatest<string[][]>(...observables: (Subscribable<never> | Subscribable<any> | PromiseLike<any> | InteropObservable<any> | ArrayLike<any> | Iterable<...> | SchedulerLike | ((...values: any[]) => string[][]))[]): Observable<...> (+38 overloads)
import combineLatest
@deprecated — Passing a scheduler here is deprecated, use {@link subscribeOn} and/or {@link observeOn} instead

'(...observables: (SchedulerLike | Subscribable<never> | Subscribable<any> | PromiseLike<any> | InteropObservable<any> | ArrayLike<...> | Iterable<...> | ((...values: any[]) => string[][]))[]): Observable<...>' is deprecatedts(6385)
```